# Grails 2 to Grails 3 conversion

Tags: grails, groovy

I am in the middle of a Grails 2 to Grails 3 migration.  After adding dependencies and importing plugins I have done some compiles and am working through errors.  I am getting this error though:

**General error during canonicalization: Cannot cast object 'org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ListExpression@1b6c954[ConstantExpression[subArrayIds]]' with class 'org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ListExpression' to class 'org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ConstantExpression'.**

Any Ideas?

Comment: A long shot but give try to run run ./gradlew clean build --stacktrace to see if you can pinpoint the error

Comment: Ended up solving myself.  This was a case where a package import needed to be modified.  Specifically grails.plugin.cache.CacheEvict is now org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheEvict